# Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import pandas as pd

def elective_choice(source_data,dest):
    print(source_path)
    df=pd.read_csv(source_path)
    rshape,cshape=df.shape
    c1=0
    c2=0
    c3=0
    c4=0
......

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.messagebox

global filename, source_path, dest_path

def source_browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var 
    # called folder_path 
    global source_path
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    source_path.set(filename)
    return filename

def dest_browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var 
    # called folder_path 
    global dest_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    dest_path.set(filename)
    return filename

def browsefunc():
    global folder_path,filename
    folder_path = StringVar()
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    Entry(textvariable=folder_path,width=60).grid(row=1, column=2)
    print(filename)
    print(folder_path)

def conversion_start():
    Label(root,text="Conversion In Progress").grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("In Progress","Please Wait\nFILE is getting ready")

def conversion_stop():
    Label(root,text="Conversion Complete").grid(row=3, column = 2)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Compete","File Conversion Complete")

root = Tk()
source_path = tkinter.StringVar()
dest_path = tkinter.StringVar()
root.title('Student Elective Choice')

Label(root,text="Source",width=12).grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(root,text="Browse",width=8,command = source_browse_button).grid(row=1, column=3)#, columnspan=3)
Entry(textvariable=source_path,width=60).grid(row=1, column=2)

Label(root,text="Destination",width=12).grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(root,text="Browse",width=8,command = dest_browse_button).grid(row=2, column=3)#, columnspan=3)
Entry(textvariable=dest_path,width=60).grid(row=2, column=2)

Button(root,text="Submit",command=lambda:[conversion_start(),elective_choice(source_path.get(),dest_path.get()),conversion_stop()]).grid(row=5, column=1)
#Label(root,text="Convertion Complete").grid(row=3, column = 2)
Button(root,text="Close",command=root.destroy).grid(row=5, column=3)
root.mainloop()
```

> PY_VAR18
>
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1558, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "", line 53, in 
>       Button(root,text="Submit",command=lambda:[conversion_start(),elective_choice(source_path.get(),dest_path.get()),conversion_stop()]).grid(row=5,
>   column=1)   File "", line 5, in
>   elective_choice
>       df=pd.read_csv(source_path)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in
>   parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 424, in
>   _read
>       filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 218, in
>   get_filepath_or_buffer
>       raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer))) ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type:

Comment: Should read `pd.read_csv(source_data)`

Comment: When ever I click on submit button. source_path.get() is not passing the correct path name to elective choice() function. Pls help me to get a solution

Comment: Have you read and understand my comment?

Comment: Initially, I overlooked my silly mistake. Yes I have modified the code and it executed perfectly.. thank you very much for your support.